# dropdown button disappear after click outside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown

I have a problem with the dropdown menu in Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.6
After clicking on the button `.dropdown` I visualize correctly the `.dropdown-menu` content, then if I click again on `.dropdown` or outside `.dropdown-menu` to close the `.dropdown` button becomes hidden.

After clicking on `.dropdown`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li role="presentation" class="dropdown open">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">...</ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Afert closing the `.dropdown-menu`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li role="presentation" class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">...</ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is there anything else going on on your site? [This example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXbrNN) works as expected. Could you post more complete markup, or (even better) a live [example that demonstrates your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The Stack Overflow question editing interface has a "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" button that can embed a live example in your question.

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict with another Javascript. Do you also use Mootools in your page?